# Comic issue where Iron Man is compared to Robert Downey Jr

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, iron-man

I remember seeing somewhere, a snapshot from a comic book where a lady (presumably a fan; might have been a reporter as well) addresses Tony Stark and says something like (paraphrased):

> *You are definitely more handsome than Robert Downey Jr.*

Looking for this comic book issue.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is famous because Robert shared a crop of the panel himself on [his Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/robertdowneyjr/photos/a.286365741531898/834747653360368/?type=3) with the caption *"Uncalled for."* which made it into a bit of a meme.

[image: RDJ shared the image where a woman says to him "You're much more handsome than Robert Downey, Junior." and Iron Man replies "So I'm told." He is stood signing autographs in the middle of a courtroom]

It took a little bit of digging around but this is from [*She-Hulk Vol. 2* Issue 27](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/She-Hulk_Vol_2_27). Iron Man enters a courtroom just behind Mallory Book to the defence of Larry Ryan in support of Jennifer Walters (She-Hulk). Below is the full panel that RDJ's post cropped it from.

[image: Panel of the above showing more people surrounding Iron Man with him signing autographs to the crowd]

Comment: I didn't know RDJ posted that.. but that's the one though..

Comment: Just checking to see if this was before or after the first Iron Man movie - they're both from 2008, so it could go either way, but the writer clearly at least knew he was cast in the role by that point.  (Interesting that the woman is calling him "handsome", despite the fact that he is completely hidden in the suit, including his face, so how would she even know?)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's the May issue and the movie was released in May.  So it would have been written before the premiere but well after  advertising for the movie had begun and trailers had been released

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, I think that just adds to the joke.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman they were both released in May if 2008 with _Iron Man_ being right at the beginning. Of note is that Tony has his helmet off at the start of the scene.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman She may even be referring to the *suit* being more handsome than the man.